# backup and restore files from .git

Tags: git, backup

I have a project use git on local ,
if I want to back up to another hard disk, should I have to copy all files and `.git` folder.
I tried `git clone /projectpath/ /backuppath/` but that still create a copy folder with the source code files.

Can I just copy the `.git` folder and there is a way recover all files from it save the disk space.
if so how to do it?

I want keep all branch and all source code ...

Comment: It's rather old now, but [the *"git cookbook"*](https://git.seveas.net/how-to-back-up-a-git-repository.html#how-to-back-up-a-git-repository) has an article that may be useful. It didn't help me b/c I'm not familiar with the *inner workings*, but I'm assuming that it's perfectly safe to make a backup ***as long as your local repo is idle during the backup***. It seems like there should be more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

This depends what you want to backup.

If you want commit history, then copy .git.

If you need only newest status of source code, 'git achieve' is ok.

Before doing all these, be sure all your modifications have been committed.

Comment: I want all source code, commit history, branch, just like original folder.  so after I copy .git to new place, what should I do?

Comment: @user1575921 Copy .git to a new folder, e.g. Backup, and run _git branch_ to list all branches and checkout worktree as you want under Backup folder. Or use it as a remote repository, _git clone file:///path_to_backup/.git_

Comment: thanks for reply, I still don't get it. after copy .git folder to new place `new` and `cd ./new` and `git branch -a` that just list all branch but how to  bring back the all source code files?

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the folder, The `.git` folder contains all the information you will need like `branches`, `tags`, `reflog`, `objects` and more.

If you want to move your project to another computer you should also copy your `.gitconfig` file located under your hoe directory as well.

Keep im mind that the when you clone project the .git folder is created locally on your machine and is not cloned, so your stash, reflog, rerere, worktree and more are "lost" if you did not copy the `.git` folder.

Comment: thanks for reply, after copy all .git folder copy to new locate, then how to restore all the source code files  ?? what command?

Comment: `git checkout <branch>` or any other code you wish to checkout

Comment: or you can print out all the .git/ref or .git/ref/heads or .git/ref/remotes.
Tell me exactly what you are looking for and ill help you out.

Comment: I did test use only one `master` project and I drag `.git` to new folder and do `git checkout master` and still don't get the files only show list `D ...  ` files name. did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

- Copy the .git folder to a new location.
- Send a reset command: "git reset --hard commit_hash"

> Ex: git reset --hard 16ddd1adb79dda40a21f4b83626fbc49e85add61

This will restore all files from the 'head' in the folder.

With Sourcetree:

- Right click the latest commit
- 'Reset current branch to this commit'